# A good Library for testing whether a minors exists in a graph?

Tags: graph-algorithms, implementation, graph-minor

I would like to know if there are any free graph libraries for testing whether a specific set of minors exists in a given graph?

Comment: I wish ! that would be an excellent ALENEX/SEA paper or set of papers.

Answer (score 5):

[NAUTY](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/nauty/) can be used as a library to help you build a hashtable for the entire poset of graph minors for small $n$.  The key would be the cannonial form given by NAUTY and the value would be a concatenation in sorted order of the cannonical forms of it's direct minors.

Comment: Yes, but nauty doesn't (as far as I know) provide any methods for *finding minors in the first place*. Also, given that the question was about merely the presence/absence of a specific set of minors, I don't see how building a hashtable out of all instances helps solve that initial problem...

Comment: Wendy Myrvold and Brendan McKay do a lot of graph minor research with NAUTY as a support library. DFS on deletions/joins until you get down to a tractable number of vertices then query the pre-computed poset. How you do the DFS will depend on what type of minor you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting! You should make that part of the answer. Also, can you give a reference? I couldn't find it.